# Paste data from different sheets to one sheet (one after the other)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to join the information of different sheets, into only one sheet. In my code, i first create a variable j that will have the value of a cell in Sheets("Folha2") (this cell only count how many rows are filled in the first column of the Sheets("Folha1"), to understand in which line can i start to paste the data from another sheet). So i only paste the data from the sheet "Portugal" to Sheet "Folha1", and after i try to paste the data from the sheet "Itália" starting in cells( j, 1).

The error is

> Method or data member not found

What did I do wrong?

```vb
Sub Macro2()

Dim j As Integer
j = Sheets("Folha2").Range("A1").Value + 1

    Range(Sheets("Portugal").Range("A1"), Sheets("Portugal").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range(Sheets("Folha1").Cells(j, 1)).Paste
    Range(Sheets("Itália").Range("A1"), Sheets("Itália").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range(Sheets("Folha1").Cells(j, 1)).Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do it:

```vb
Sub Macro4()

    Range(Sheets("Portugal").Range("A1"), Sheets("Portugal").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Folha1").Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range(Sheets("Itália").Range("A2"), Sheets("Itália").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Folha1").Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're doing, but if I'm right you can reduce your code to this:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim j As Long

'j = Sheets("Folha2").Range("A1").Value + 1

Sheets("Portugal").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("Folha1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
Sheets("Italia").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("Folha1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. what i really want to do is paste the value from sheet "Portugal" to sheet "Folha1", and after that, paste the value of sheet "Itália" to sheet "Folha1" after the data that i have already paste, to make a continuous list of data.

Comment: That's what that code does. Need more info - a screenshot of your data might help.